# Changing images on timer and starting onClick

Tags: java, android

I am making this app with dice. When an user touches the image of the die the image changes to a random other die. To make it look like the user 'throws' the dice, the images changes a few times (6) before it stops at a random image. Here is an example of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int changes = 0;
int n;
int[] heads = {R.drawable.dice1,R.drawable.dice2,R.drawable.dice3,
        R.drawable.dice4,R.drawable.dice5,R.drawable.dice6};
Handler handler;
boolean Running = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(Running){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(200);}
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable(){

                    public void run(){
                        Random rdm = new Random();
                        n = rdm.nextInt(6);

                         ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDice1);
                         image.setImageResource(heads[n]);
                         changes++;

                         if(changes == 6){
                        Running = false;
                        changes == 0;
                        }
                    }


                });
            }

   };

};

  new Thread(runnable).start();

    }

   public void imageClick(View v) {  
    Running = true;   //this has no effect.

 }

}
```

After the dices changes 6 times (changes == 6) it stops. This works but the problem is that it won't run when clicked on the image (imageClick). Other commands do work in imageClick, but 'Running = true' doens't. What should I write there in order to make the user 'throw' the dice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put that Thread in onclick

```
   public void imageClick(View v) {  
    Running = true;
    new Thread(runnable).start(); // start the thread when image is clicked
 }
```

also declare runnable as a member variable.

```
Runnable runnable;
```

and in onCreate

```
runnable = new Runnable(){.......
```

Comment: This gives an error: 'runnable can not be resolved to a variable'.

Comment: oh . you need to declare the runnable as field .. editing the answer